# Find the solution set from Ax = b, without any extra calculations

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

**Given**

```
 A =                          b = 
|  1   2  4   8 |                 | 10 |
| 1/2  3  6  12 |                 | 15 |   
| 1/4  1  2  12 |                 | 13 |
```

**The LU factorization of A is**

L =

```
   |  1    0   0 |
   | 1/2   1   0 |
   | 1/4  1/4  1 |
```

U =

```
| 1  2  4  8 |
| 0  2  4  8 |
| 0  0  0  8 |
```

**Reduced echelon of A is :**

```
| 1  0  0  0 |
| 0  1  2  0 |
| 0  0  0  1 |
```

**Amount of independant collumns :**

```
i think 2 -- collumn 2 and 3 are dependant
```

**The basis for the zerospace :**

```
x1 = 0
x2 = -2x3
x4 = 0
```

thus

```
|  0 |
| -2 |
|  1 |  (free)
|  0 |
```

**The bases for the column space is :**

```
|  1   2   8 |
| 1/2  3  12 |  
| 1/4  1  12 |
```

---

**Asked :**

*Vector b is the sum of the 2de and 4the column of A. What is the solution set of Ax=b? Without using ANY EXTRA calculations. Why do i have all the ingredients for writing the solution immediatley ? *

Answer from matlab:

```
|  0  |
|  0  |
| 1/2 |
|  1  |
```

Answer (score 0):

Since $b = a_2 + a_4$ and $2a_2 = a_3$ you have
$$A(e_2+e_4) = A(\frac{1}{2}e_3 + e_4) = b$$
Therefor the Solution set is the 1-dimensional affine subspace containing
$$e_2+e_4, \frac{1}{2}e_3+e_4$$